# How to generate a sequence that converges to $1/n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am curious how to generate a sequence $(a_n)$ that converges to $1/k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ when $n \to 
\infty$. Of course one can think of a sequence that converges to $1/k$ for specific $k$, but I found it hard to find out general rules for any $k$. Can anyone tell what it would be?

Edit: I wanted to exclude the case of $(1/n)$ being a sequence.

Comment: What about $\left(\dfrac 1 n\right)_{\color{red}k\in \mathbb N}$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want a sequence $a_k$ such that $a_k \to 1/n$ as $k\to \infty$? Or do you want a sequnce whose limit points include $1/n$ for every $n$? Or maybe something completely different?

Comment: I edited my question. I think everyone misunderstood my question... Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{(k+1)^j}\quad=>\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac1k$$

Comment: Question: can you show me how the sum converges to $1/k$? Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^nx^j=\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, by multiplying both sides with the denominator of the latter, and then opening up the parentheses on the left hand side. All the terms will vanish, except for the first and the last. Then, for $|x|<1$ and $n\to\infty$, we have $x^n\to0$. In our case, $x=\dfrac1{k+1}$. After simplifying the new expression, just subtract $x^0=1$, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, just perturb it with something that converges faster. Two immediate ideas:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
or, if you think this is cheating:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

That's if I understood correctly and you want a sequence that asymptotically becomes like $o(1/n)$.

If you want to generate a sequence with another parameter, you could do it like
$b_m=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m^2}$
and you are there.

Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve.